# Updating pyenv when switching to a Python buffer

Tags: python, hooks

I use pyenv to maintain my python versions and virtualenvs. I really like the way you can create a local `.python-version` for each project, pointing to the version I need. I use `pyenv-mode` which allows me to set the right `pyenv` version pretty easily. The problem is that I tend to keep a single emacs server running, so when I switch between buffers in different projects I have to manually switch my pyenv, and if the python version is different I also have to restart the RPC server. I'm trying to automate this, and I found a great library to enable me to run hooks when I switch buffers (https://github.com/10sr/switch-buffer-functions-el).

Here's what I have so far, but it doesn't seem to be working at all (neither the if or then clauses execute):

```lisp
(add-hook 'switch-buffer-functions
          (lambda (prev cur)
            (if (string-equal "Python" (format-mode-line mode-name nil nil (get-buffer cur)))
                (lambda ()
                  (message "Switching python buffer")
                  (pyenv-use-corresponding)
                  (elpy-rpc-restart))
              (lambda ()
                (message "Switched to non-python buffer"))
              )))
```

however if I do something like:

```lisp
(add-hook 'switch-buffer-functions
          (lambda (prev cur)
            (message (format-mode-line mode-name nil nil (get-buffer cur)))))
```

it seems like it should work as expected as it does print the `mode-name`. I also tested the `if` comparison with `M-:` and it seems to work.... anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what I needed was `progn` instead of a lambda function. My full working code now, including a check for only re-starting `elpy-rpc` if the `pyenv` actually changed (so that it's not constantly restarting it when switching to MiniBuffer)

```lisp
(use-package switch-buffer-functions
  :config
  (add-hook 'switch-buffer-functions
            (lambda (prev cur)
              (if (string-equal "Python" (format-mode-line mode-name nil nil cur))
                  (progn
                    (setq old_pyenv (pyenv--active-python-version))
                    (pyenv-use-corresponding)
                    (setq new_pyenv (pyenv--active-python-version))

                    (if (not (string-equal old_pyenv new_pyenv))
                        (message "restarting rpc")
                        (elpy-rpc-restart))
                    )
                )))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to go is to use https://github.com/direnv/direnv to manage the pipenv activation in your shell.  This way the env var manipulation happens whenever you change directories in your shell.

Then for Emacs use https://github.com/wbolster/emacs-direnv, which integrates direnv into Emacs when buffers are switched.  You might still need to hook in to switch-buffer-functions to restart elpy stuff as needed though.